Water leaking in ac/water heater closet
We recently moved into downstairs apartment. A week ago I noticed a puddle outside the closet that has ac and hot water heater in it. The floor under the water heater pan and surrounding it is wet, besides wood at back wall. They brought in one plumber who didn't do anything besides slip a sleeve on one pipe that had a small drip. Still had puddling going on. Then 2nd plumbers came fixed several pipes and replaced the water heater. Dryed up all the water. After they left I went over to closet and water was coming out and puddling. I've been wet vacuuming up water about every hour for a week now. Don't see anything dripping. Maintenance man couldn't figure it out. He checked in upstairs closet and apartment behind us and didn't see any visible leaks. Question is where would all this water coming from?

AC drip pan is overflowing

Checked that also, it's not overflowing

how about the ceiling

lets do a Sherlock Holmes,
dry the floor really well,
use bread flower and spray it, stand back and observe where the water comes from
